# Filling a chekboxes in Firefox with an apple Script

Tags: firefox, applescript

I want to fill a form automatically in a Firefox page with an apple script. There are about thirty clicks to make in different checkboxes ("yes" or "no") to fill the hole form.

I try to use such mouse instructions with different X and Y, to let the mouse clicking at different places on the Firefox page
for example something like:-

```
tell application "System Events"
       click at {66, 43}
end tell
```

But no good results, sorry, I am a beginner !!!

Comment: Please provide the URL of the web page you're trying to run the AppleScript on.

Comment: I could try with any page. For example https://www.wikipedia.org/ but I could try everything else. It doesn't work

Comment: There are no check boxes on the page that loads from the URL in your comment! Sorry, but I cannot help if you do not provide a real working web page URL that anyone can access. I'm not going hunting and work on something you haven tried. That said, I suggest you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, Firefox is not really AppleScript friendly and suggest you use Safari or Google Chrome for your AppleScript Browser scripting needs.